# Maintaining session info through out all the pages is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I implemented a '$cookieStore' of '[ng-cookies]' using angular js for login/logout functionality.
I followed the documentation mentioned here (in Take2): http://maffrigby.com/maintaining-session-info-in-angularjs-when-you-refresh-the-page/

and here is my code snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('TaskManager', ['ngCookies']);

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {

  $scope.login = function(str) {
    console.log(".......... login called......");
    var validEmail = validateEmail(email.value);
    if (validEmail && password.value != "") {

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../TaskManager/public/user/login',
    data: $.param({
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
    .success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    var result = data.response;
    console.log(result);

    if (result == "success") {
      $scope.userId = data.user_id;
      $scope.email = data.email;
      $scope.Name = data.name;
      $scope.password = data.password;
      $scope.Type = data.type;

      //storing value at cookieStore
      $cookieStore.put("loggedin", "true");          

      document.getElementById('hiddenForm').setAttribute("action", "./Dashboard.html");
      document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();

    } else alert(data.message);
  });



  app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.loggedIn = $cookieStore.get("loggedin");
    ....................................
    ....................................


 });

   app.controller('ReportController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {

        $scope.loggedIn = $cookieStore.get("loggedin");
        ....................................
        ....................................
    });

   app.controller('TaskController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {

        $scope.loggedIn = $cookieStore.get("loggedin");
        ....................................
        ....................................
    });
```

It's working fine for the LoginController and DashboardController but for the remaining controllers it gives error as : **Uncaught Error: No module: ngCookies**.

while I have same code in all the pages. As in html files I specified my app as ng-app="TaskManager":

```
<html ng-app="TaskManager">
```

the error : **Uncaught Error: No module: ngCookies**, is not understanable for me.

Any suggesstion would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for being obvious, but did you include the ngCookies script on all pages?

Comment: @ Joao Leal... thanks a lot. Such a stupid mistake I made. would you please post it as answer I would like to accept the most quickest answer. Again thank you for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may have forgotten to include the ngCookies script in the pages that aren't working. :)